# ASP.Net RegEx with ampersand and spaces

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am using the following regular expression to find words and phrases in a document. (Have to use regular expression and have to use `\b`.)

```
\b (zoo|a & b|dummy)\b
```

When I try to find matches in the following string

```
going to the zoo with a & b
```

`a & b` doesn't get matched. However, if I remove the leading and following space from the string and regex, making both `a&b`, it matches, but I do need to those spaces.

Comment: Your regex [matches for me](http://regex101.com/r/zI8eJ1). You mean that `\b a&b\b` matches `a & b` but `\b a & b\b` doesn't?

Comment: No. \b a&b\b matches a&b but \b a & b\b doesn't match a & b.

Comment: It doesn't match here http://regex101.com/r/hU9zT9#pcre

Comment: You need to add the global flag `g` to look for multiple matches instead of stopping at the first: `/\b(zoo|a & b|dummy)\b/g`, see http://regex101.com/r/hN7wB4

Comment: That did the trick. Why don't you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use \s for spaces

```
string strRegex = @"\b\s(zoo|a\s&\sb|dummy)\b";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"going to the zoo with a & b";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    Console.WriteLine(myMatch); 
}
```